# Calculate the maximum number of consecutive digits in a string of discontinuous digits

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataframe inside a column data is **[1,1,2,3,4,7,8,8,15,19,20,21]**. I want to get the most contiguous data segments in this column: **[1,2,3,4]**. How to calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create groups by consecutive values by compare difference with cumulative sum, get counts by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and last filter maximal counts of original column `col` - output are all consecutive values with maximal counts:

```
s = df['col'].groupby(df['col'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()).transform('size')

out = df.loc[s.eq(s.max()), 'col']
```

If need first maximum consecutives values use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
s = df['col'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()

out = df.loc[s.eq(s.value_counts().idxmax()), 'col']
```